# Battle.net server location

Tags: battle.net

I'll be spending quite some time on one of those specific locations on Earth where connections may or may not be faster not depending on geo-distance but on several other factors.

Anyone knows the IP's of Blizzard Battle.net servers from:

- USA
- Europe
- Asia
- Australia

So that I can ping them and better decide which server to choose from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out their traceroute help guide

http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/performing-a-traceroute

**Diablo III players should replace the xs with the IP address of the region they are trying to connect to.  US - 12.129.209.68; EU - 213.155.155.233; KR - 182.162.134.1**

This looks to be their login servers, but who knows, may help you.